# Knockout dropdown cascade option not update

Tags: ajax, knockout.js

I'm trying to populate default value for dependent dropdown using knockout.

When values are harcoded it works, but I need to get values from ajax request and then, the second dropdown option is not updated. The value self.selectedState is updated but I guess that as I haven't already the options populated, then value in select is not bind.  This is my code so far:

```js
function myViewModel(country, state) {
 var self = this;
  self.selectedCountry = ko.observable();
 self.selectedState = ko.observable();
  
  self.availableCountries = ko.observableArray([
   {
    id: 1, name: 'United States', states: [
    { id: 1, name: 'Alabama' },
        { id: 2, name: 'California' },
   ]
  },
  {
   id: 2, name: 'Canada', states: [
    { id: 53, name: 'Alberta' },
   ]
  }
 ]);
  
  self.availableStates = ko.observableArray([]);
 
  self.selectedCountry.subscribe(function() {
  self.availableStates([]);
  
  for (var i = 0; i < self.availableCountries().length; i++) {
   if (self.availableCountries()[i].id == self.selectedCountry()) {
    self.availableStates(self.availableCountries()[i].states);
    break;
   }
  }
 });
  
  self.selectedCountry(1).selectedState(2);
}

var viewModel = new myViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select data-bind="options: availableCountries, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', optionsCaption: 'Select a country...',
value: selectedCountry"></select>

<select data-bind="options: availableStates, optionsText: 'name',optionsValue: 'id', value: selectedState, visible: availableStates().length > 0" style="display:none"></select>
```

Is there something special that needs to be done when options are obtained from ajax?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k5bch6gL/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue isn't AJAX, specifically, but the fact that `self.selectedState` doesn't have a corresponding `option` for some time (while the options are being fetched).
From [the docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html#using-valueallowunset-with-select-elements):

> Normally, when you use the `value` binding on a `<select>` element, it
>   means that you want the associated model value to describe which item
>   in the `<select>` is selected. But what happens if you set the model
>   value to something that has no corresponding entry in the list? The
>   default behavior is for Knockout to overwrite your model value to
>   reset it to whatever is already selected in the dropdown, thereby
>   preventing the model and UI from getting out of sync.
>
> However, sometimes you might not want that behavior. If instead you
>   want Knockout to allow your model observable to take values that have
>   no corresponding entry in the `<select>`, then specify `valueAllowUnset:
>   true`. In this case, whenever your model value cannot be represented in
>   the `<select>`, then the `<select>` simply has no selected value at that
>   time, which is visually represented by it being blank.

Comment: Thank you so much buddy. I never understand in which case should I use that valueAllowUnset bind until now.

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect opportunity to make use of a computed observable. A computed seems to a good fit for this job because it will save you from setting up your own manual subscriptions at track dependencies for you. Give it a try - I've changed **very** little of your code to accomplish this..

```js
function myViewModel(country, state) {
  var self = this;
  self.selectedCountry = ko.observable();
  self.selectedState = ko.observable();

  self.availableCountries = ko.observableArray([{
    id: 1,
    name: 'United States',
    states: [{ id: 1, name: 'Alabama' }, 
             { id: 2, name: 'California' }, ] 
    }, 
    { id: 2, 
      name: 'Canada',
      states: [{ id: 53, name: 'Alberta' }, ]
  }]);

  self.availableStates = ko.computed(function() {
    var states = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < self.availableCountries().length; i++) {
      if (self.availableCountries()[i].id == self.selectedCountry()) {
        states = states.concat(self.availableCountries()[i].states);
        break;
      }
    }
    return states;
  });

  self.selectedCountry(1).selectedState(2);
}

var viewModel = new myViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select data-bind="options: availableCountries, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', optionsCaption: 'Select a country...',
value: selectedCountry"></select>

<select data-bind="options: availableStates, optionsText: 'name',optionsValue: 'id', value: selectedState, visible: availableStates().length > 0" style="display:none"></select>
```